# How to connect Azure Database migration service with on premise based source SQL server

Tags: sql-server, vpn, azure, database, sql

I am trying to connect Azure Database migration service with SQL server which is in On premise VPN. Not able to establish the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple of prerequisites that you need to verify

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/pre-reqs#prerequisites-common-across-migration-scenarios

**I would start with the following:**

- Open your Windows Firewall to allow the Azure Database Migration Service to access the source SQL Server, which by default is TCP port 1433.
- If you are running multiple named SQL Server instances using dynamic ports, you may wish to enable the SQL Browser Service and allow access to UDP port 1434 through your firewalls so that the Azure Database Migration Service can connect to a named instance on your source server.
- Create a server-level firewall rule for the Azure SQL Database server to allow the Azure Database Migration Service access to the target databases. Provide the subnet range of the VNET used for the Azure Database Migration Service.